# Validate a user account and get the corresponding email id using clent side object model managed code

Tags: user-profile, authentication

I am using client object model to add items to splist. Here one field which is the email id I need to fill automatically after validation. If the user has a valid domain id. I want to extract the mail id

```
public static string checkUserEmail(string username, ClientContext clientContext)
        {
            string strEmail = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                //ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(strSiteURL);
                //clientContext.Load();
                //List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TOM");
                //ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                //clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                string strUserName = username.Trim();
                User domainUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(strUserName);

                if (domainUser.ServerObjectIsNull == false)
                {
                    strEmail = domainUser.Email;
                }
                else
                {
                    strEmail = "";
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User check error {0}", ex.Message);
            }
            return strEmail;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this:

```
string strUserName = username.Trim();
User domainUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser(strUserName);
clientContext.Load(domainUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (domainUser.ServerObjectIsNull == false)
{
   strEmail = domainUser.Email;
}
else
{
   strEmail = "";
}
```